# How do I use docker services within a android emulator

Tags: docker, android-studio, docker-compose

I'm trying to consume a HTTP service within an Android emulator. The service is hosted as a docker container using docker compose.

From my machine, browsing to `http://localhost:<port>` returns a result. Happy days...
From within the emulator, it failed immediately. Fair enough, the service isn't running in the emulator.
So I'll try to get from `http://10.0.2.2:<port>`. This comes back with a timeout error.

I'm assuming I'm missing some sort of bridge but I don't know how to set that up.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT**
To add more information, I'm using docker desktop for Windows. Not sure if `network_mode` would work, but I have a few services that need to run in the same compose script, so I need to be able to use port mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I made a mistake in the config which meant I was pointing to the wrong URL

Using `http://10.0.2.2:<port>` works in my case.

Thanks